# How to get parent product collection from child product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, join

I have a simple product collection and I want to get a collection of parent products from the child product collection.

```
$child_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',array('eq'=>'value'));
```

How can I get the parent product collection from this child products collection?

Comment: Have you got simple product id?

Comment: I have a simple product **collection**, I want to get parent collection without cycle of simple products to obtain ID